# Creating Django sessions

Tags: django, django-sessions

I am facing a problem while building a Django web app.
I want that if a user logs into his account, his session should be stored and when he agains visits the login page ,he should be redirected to his home page. I have tried using

Here is my code.

Views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Index Page")

@login_required
def home(request):
    ctx = {}
    return render_to_response('auth/home.html',ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$','apps.auth.views.index'),

)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'cc/', login, kwargs = {'template_name' : 'auth/cc.html'} , name = 'cc_login'),
url(r'logout/', logout, name = 'cc_logout'),
url(r'home/','apps.auth.views.home', name = 'cc_home'),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same situation with my django project.

I solved it by making a view that was similar too:

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(<insert your desired page here>)
    else:
        return render(<whatever the login page is>)
```

This way, if the user is logged in, they will be redirected to whatever page you want them to be.

EDIT:

In response to the comments below, I am modifying my answer (original is still above). 
Here is what I have done to solve your problem.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

def custom_login(request, **kwargs):
    """
        Redirects the user to the desired page if they are authenticated
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(<whatever page or view you want them to go to>)
    else:
        return login(request, **kwargs)
```

For example, your kwargs could be {'template_name': 'your_login_template.html', 'authentication_form': YourCustomRegistrationFormClass}

If you're using the standard login and registration procedures, just leave the kwargs part blank.

Comment: Thanks buched but I am not able to render my template when passed as a parameter. The template contains inbuilt django form {{form.as_p}}.
It does not views that. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question exactly, but your problem might be caused by not calling the render function properly. you can find an explanation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/.

To call the render function, you will need to pass in the proper parameters (e.g. render(request, 'your_template.html', {dictionary of context variables}).

Comment: To clarify further, the 'form' for the 'form.as_p' that you use in the  render context dictionary should be passed in like this 
    render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form': your_form})

Comment: Thanks buched. I have used Django's inbuilt form, ie  'form.as_p'. So, what exactly should goes into {'form': your_form}.

Comment: PS: I have not made any form for login, rather I have used the inbuilt form. Replacing 'your_form' with 'form.as_p' does not works.

Comment: I have modified the answer above to try and answer your question.

Comment: If you're using the standard login view, don't worry about the form.as_p thing. By redirecting to django's builtin login view, the form variable will be passed into the template you specify and should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Django, but have you tried overriding the default login view?

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session.set_expiry(0) # Remember user session
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(USER_PAGE_ADDRESS)
    return auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'cc/', APP_NAME.views.login, kwargs = {'template_name' : 'auth/cc.html'} , name = 'cc_login'),
    ...
)
```

Comment: @user1162512 sorry I don't have enough points to respond to buched post, but have you tried passing your login function additional arguments (like *args and **kwargs) as I did in my answer above? Then it would know to expect the template argument.